# I can't rails a server when i create a project with mysql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I create a rails project without using mysql, I can rails server and read in the browser in http://localhost:3000.Also I can create datebase into sqlite. But after I rails new [filename] -d mysql, I can't rails server and most of command are missing symbol called. I am sure that I am open my mysql server. But I can't find any problem. Also, I am sure that I am in the correct location, because when I add gem "mysql2"into Gemfile and rails server, it will display

```
[!] There was an error parsing Gemfile: You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version requirements.You specified: mysql2 (~> 0.5.3) and mysql2 (>= 0). Bundler cannot continue.
```

It is my first time ask question in here and this my english is not good, I hope the form is correct.

```
rake db:create
dyld[75423]: missing symbol called
zsh: abort      rake db:create
rails server
dyld[75560]: missing symbol called
zsh: abort      rails server
```

Comment: 1) Fix the Gemfile (remove duplicated mysql2 dependency), 2) `bundle install`. Do you see any errors? If not, proceed to the db setup. If yes, fix the errors. It doesn't make **any** sense to try running server without the properly finished dv setup, and trying to do db setup without properly installed db-related dependencies.

Comment: i'am sorry that I forget when i rails server with mysql, it will display run  bundle binstubs bundler
       rails  importmap:install
dyld[18667]: missing symbol called
       rails  turbo:install stimulus:install
dyld[18678]: missing symbol called